# How to send aes encrypted Multipart Entity file and parameters with Retrofit to the server?

Tags: android, encryption, retrofit2, aes, multipartentity

How to send **aes** encrypted Multipart Entity file and parameters with Retrofit to the server in Android?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Multipart
@POST("yourapi")
Call<ResponseBody> addRecord(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
                            

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if ((requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) && (resultCode == -1)) {

    File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()));

    MultipartBody.Part multipartBody =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.getName(),requestFile);

    Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = service.addRecord( multipartBody);
    responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d("Success", "success "+response.code());
            Log.d("Success", "success "+response.message());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
            Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but t's not encrypted!